# Induced Current in Uniform B-Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current

> In each of the following cases, mark the directions of the induced current $I$ in the conductor and the magnetic force $F$ acting on the conductor when the circuit moves in the direction as shown.
>
> [image]

Sorry for a basic question here, but I don't really understand the question in the book.

a) no current / no magnetic force
b) no current / no magnetic force
c) current - anti-clockwise / magnetic force - down
d) current - anti-clockwise / magnetic force - left

May I know why a) & b) have no current / no magnetic force ?

Answer (score 1):

Current is caused by the *change* in magnetic flux passing through the loop.

In both parts (a) and (b), there is no magnetic flux passing through the loop because the magnetic field is directed parallel to it. If you move the loop now keeping its orientation the same, the flux will remain zero. As there is no change in flux, there is no current induced.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.  However, I may miunderstand (or I can't read the diagram correctly) the sentence "conductor moves into the page".  In figure b) , is "conductor moving into page" still a parallel to the magnetic field instead of perpendicular ?

Comment: Look, given the orientation of the loop in a uniform magnetic field, there is zero flux passing through it. Now as the field is uniform, howsoever you move the loop keeping its orientation unaltered, the flux will remain zero. If you tilt the loop, then the flux could have changed or if you could have taken it out of the field as in the later two parts.

Comment: I hope you are not confusing with the two different directions that need to be considered - the direction of the magnetic field passing through loop which determines the flux and the direction of motion of loop. What I am saying is that in a uniform magnetic field whatever the direction of motion of loop  and whatever the initial flux, as long as orientation is unaltered, the flux will not change because B.A is unchanged.